# Qt 3D bar graph becomes unresponsive on large sizes

Tags: qt, 3d

I am currently working on a Qt project which should simulate a bar graph with a dimension of 360x360. While the code i wrote works, it is sluggish and unresponsive when it is simulating a bar graph of size 360x360 This problem does not exist for smaller sized 3D bar graphs like 8x12 and etc. What can i do to make my code run more smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Qt 3D Bar Graph was meant for such big data sets. In fact, having 360^2 bars probably doesn't look like a bar graph any more :).

What you can do is to replace it with regular 3D rendering where you create entire graphics on your own.

If your data doesn't change often then you could build static mesh that resembles a 3D bar graph and just render it in OpenGL.

If your data change often or you want to animate your graph then you could push your data into 2D texture, build initial, flat mesh and use this texture in Vertex Shader to displace mesh vertices. This way you could animate all your data and get fluid framerate.